# Why didn't Steven try to follow through with his threat?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, moon-knight, moon-knight-2022

In Episode 2 of *Moon Knight*, after discovering a bag of illegal items belonging to Marc Spector in a storage locker, Steven Grant declares that he's going to take the bag to the police, confess Marc's crimes, and get himself committed to an institution, all to prevent Marc from hurting anyone ever again.

Later in the episode, the police arrive at Steven's apartment, discover the bag, and arrest him. This seems like the perfect opportunity for Steven to carry out his threat, but instead, he insists that the bag is not his, that Marc Spector is a different person, and that he didn't do any of the things Marc is accused of.

It's clear that Steven hasn't changed his mind about Marc being dangerous. When he's left alone in the police car, he point-blank tells Marc that he is never letting him take control ever again.

Of course, the officers turned out to be members of Harrow's cult, and would have taken Steven to Harrow regardless of what he said or did, but Steven didn't know that. So the question remains: **Why didn't Steven try to follow through with his threat, given that he seemingly had a perfect opportunity to do so?** Did he simply chicken out of it? Did something happen during the conversation with Layla to change his mind? Or did he still genuinely believe that he and Marc are two separate people, even after their conversation in the storage locker?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It all has to do with Layla and it's probably twofold really. During the conversation with her, Steven realizes that he has a lot in common with her and pretty much falls for her. This culminates with him saying he wouldn't divorce her (if *he* was married to her).

> **Steven:** Divo... Divorce?
>
> **Layla:** Yeah, we doing this or not?
>
> **Steven:** I would never divorce you.
>
> <sub>*Moon Knight*, Season 1 Episode 2, "Summon the Suit"</sub>

At the same time, he realizes Layla has quite a great understanding of what is going on, more so than himself. As such he can probably find out a lot from her that can help him. No point in getting himself locked up if he can be free and help himself. If it fails he can always go back to plan A of going to the police. This culminates when he tells Layla she can have the scarab and pretty much says just that.

> **Steven:** I am not Marc Spector. I'm Steven Grant. I work in a gift shop. Well, I used to work in a gift shop. And I think I'm in real danger, and I think maybe that you might be the only person that can help me.
>
> <sub>*Moon Knight*, Season 1 Episode 2, "Summon the Suit"</sub>

As you point out he obviously still wants to keep control of himself and doesn't trust Marc. But trusting Marc and going to the police are the only options he has, and here Layla has presented him with a third option, and that's what he took in the moment when given the choice.